# Can't seem to run JavaFX project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I installed Oracle-8 for Java and downloaded the e(fx)clipse bundle from http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/.

However, now I'm running into this error message:

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class ui.project.Main
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$50(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/Utils
    at org.controlsfx.tools.Platform.getCurrentPlatform(Platform.java:65)
    at org.controlsfx.tools.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:41)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.HeavyweightDialog.<clinit>(HeavyweightDialog.java:72)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.DialogFactory.createDialog(DialogFactory.java:58)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:295)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialogs.buildDialog(Dialogs.java:1086)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialogs.showCommandLinks(Dialogs.java:692)
    at ui.project.Main.welcomeWindow(Main.java:175)
    at ui.project.Main.<init>(Main.java:64)
    ... 13 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.Utils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application ui.project.Main
```

Main 64 calls method welcomeWindow in line 175 which includes this line:

```
Action response = Dialogs.create()
            .title("Welcome to the Dolphin UI")
            .masthead(null)
            .message("Please select an option to proceed.")
            .showCommandLinks(links.get(3), links);
```

Comment: Would you mind showing a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: The code itself is pretty big that it's not really possible. There seems to be two errors from my Main class and I've listed them above.

Comment: I guess my biggest issue is this line: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.Utils but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Did you manage to have javafx work ?

Comment: For instance, can you get [this example from oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm) working ?

Comment: Yes, JavaFX works. I got the example to work. I can create new projects easily but for some reason, this particular project is giving me issues now when it worked a while ago (I had to change my environment around but I'm on Oracle-8 again). I also installed Netbeans and ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending roughly 8 hours on this, using three different operating systems (Ubuntu 32, 64 and Windows 8.1), the issue was with Java. Apparently, any version after 8u40 will not work with this.

Comment: So, the answer is "If you use Java 8 you can't use JavaFX"? This is a very unclear answer.

Comment: You can certainly use it but the specific code I was working with would not work past 8u40

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that the class com.sun.javafx.Utils was moved to com.sun.javafx.util.Utils package in update 60 of Java 8.

I see that you use ControlsFX in your code. Then, take a new version of ControlsFX solve this problem.

More info:
https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/526/comsunjavafxutils-changes-to

Comment: ControlsFX and JavaFX 8u60:
http://fxexperience.com/2015/08/controlsfx-and-javafx-8u60/